# Entity Framework - When querying a single column, how do I tell the difference between no results and a result with a NULL value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a class in EF named `vw_Project` with a property `ProjectTitle` of type string, among other properties. I want to run an efficient LINQ query which only queries the first column of the first record in my results (the first "cell", similar to `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`). I might write something like this:

```
string projectTitle = context.vw_Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectID == projID)
    .Select(p => p.ProjectTitle)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is, I can't tell whether my query got zero results, or if it simply got one result with a value of `NULL` for that `varchar` column.

I could always query the whole object to make that determination, then extract the `ProjectTitle` column into a string variable in memory, but I'd be querying a bunch of columns I don't need, which is a poor solution. That would look like this:

```
string projectTitle;
vw_Project project = context.vw_Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectID == projID)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (project != null)
{
    projectTitle = project.ProjectTitle;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid Project ID");
}
```

How do I make this determination without querying additional columns or rows?

Comment: I don't think the bottom solution is "poor": unless you eagerly load collections on the `Project`, the overhead would be hard to detect. You should combine `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`, i.e. `FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projID)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good suggestion on the `FirstOrDefault` — I'll update my answer accordingly. As for the other solution suggesting getting the whole object from the database, you're right, in most cases it won't make a huge difference. But if it's a large table, especially one with computed columns, or if you need to get several rows rather than just one, it's an important optimization that shouldn't be forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still determine whether you got zero results or a `NULL` record if you create an in-line anonymous type with only the property you need.

```
string projectTitle;
var result = context.vw_Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectID == projID)
    .Select(p => new { p.ProjectTitle })
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    projectTitle = result.ProjectTitle;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid Project ID");
}
```

If the query gets a result, the `result` instance will not be null, regardless of whether the internal `ProjectTitle` property is null.

Comment: Note that `Take(1)` is redundant. `FirstOrDefault` does the same thing.

Comment: @GertArnold You're absolutely right. Just corrected it in my answer and response.